# Are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ isomorphic as groups under addition?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

The title says it all:

Are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ isomorphic as groups under addition?

(By $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ I mean the cartesian product of countably-infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?
What have you tried?

Comment: And what do you mean by "homomorphic"?

Comment: Do you mean "isomorphic as abelian groups"?

Comment: edited the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ both have cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, and are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$.
The following lemma may be helpful:

**Lemma.** Let $X, Y$ be vector spaces over a field $F$. If $|X| = |Y| > |F| \ge \aleph_0$, then $X, Y$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.

*Proof.* Let $I$ be an index set for a basis of $X$ over $F$. We have that
$$
|X| =
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \left|{I \choose i}\right| |F \setminus \{0\}|^i.
$$
Since $F$ is infinite, $|F \setminus \{0\}|^i = |F|$.
If $I$ were finite, we would have $\left|{I \choose i}\right| < \aleph_0$,
$|X| \le \aleph_0^2 |F| = |F|$, contradicting our assumption that $|X| > |F|$.
So $I$ is infinite, so $\left|{I \choose i}\right| = |I|$.
So $|X| = \aleph_0 |I| |F| = |I|$.

Similarly, let $J$ be an index set for a basis of $Y$ over $F$, and we have
$|Y| = |J|$.

Therefore we conclude $|I| = |J|$; then there is a bijection $f: I \to J$.
Mapping each basis element $\alpha_i$ of $X$ to the basis element $\beta_{f(i)}$ of $Y$ we have an isomorphism of $X$ and $Y$.
$\square$

Now note that isomorphic vector spaces are in particular isomorphic as abelian groups.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. To see that, note that $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ are isomorphic as $\Bbb{Q}$-vector spaces. Indeed, they are isomorphic iff they have the same $\Bbb{Q}$-dimension, and they have the same $\Bbb{Q}$-dimension because they have the same cardinality.

Isomorphic vector spaces are, in particular, isomorphic as abelian groups. So $\Bbb{R} \cong \Bbb{R}^\infty$.

Comment: "and they have the same $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension because they have the same cardinality." This is not correct, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^2$ have the same cardinality. But for infinite dimension this seems true.

Comment: Of course, here it works because they both have infinite $\Bbb{Q}$-dimension.

Comment: For infinite dimensional vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{K}$ (where $|X|$ denoted cardinality) we have $|V| = |\mathbb{K}| \mathrm{dim}(V)$. So for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$, we have $|V| = |\mathbb{Q}| \mathrm{dim}(V) = \mathrm{dim}(V)$ (since $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ is infinite). Thus the cardinality of these vector spaces and their dimensions are the same thing. This particular result now follows from: $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$